# How to Use VM argument while creating build of an Application?

Tags: eclipse, javafx

My `Javafx` application was taking so much memory.

I read about `-Xmx VM` arguments in `Eclipse` and applied.

It gave me good result. After using this maximum memory was `76000k`. But when I created build of that project it again start consuming more than `10000k` and contentiously increasing.

Suggest some ideas and edit if i'm wrong in my language.

Comment: It is never a good idea to keep increasing the Head space. You should try to debug your application in the first place that why is it taking too much space.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion Sir. But I resolved that issue, my application was like ODesk app, which take snapshots after intervals.
I just give dimensions to image which displays as notification.
Then memory consumption came into limit.